# Saving data to a SQL Server 2000 database

Tags: .net, sql-server-2000

I have a form that users can add links to via a popup. When the user adds a link from the popup the link appears in the form however I do not want the link path saved to the database unless the user saves the form.

The user can add as many links as they like. How would you recommend handling this? I thought about passing a delimited string of link paths to the stored procedure when saving the form.

Does this sound like a good idea? I'm thinking max character count could be a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a `Links` table that has a one-to-many relationship to the rest of the form saved data. In your stored proc, you can loop through the passed data and do an insert to this table for each properly formatted link.

Comment: Yes i know that but in sqlserver 2000 as far as i know there is a limit of 8000 characters on sql params set as type varchar.  I was asking about how to handle this part. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Richard Banks Each parameter can have a maxlength of 8000 characters, are you suggesting that you have a single parameter `@LinkText` that takes in a concatenation of all link text? Or are your links longer than 8000 characters?